# Bug with LinearProgramming on Integers?

Tags: bugs, version-7, mathematical-optimization

With *Mathematica* 7:

```
LinearProgramming[{1, 1}, {{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {1, 1}, Automatic, Integers]
```

gives wrong result `{0,1}`. But

```
LinearProgramming[{1, 1}, {{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {1, 1}, Automatic, Reals]
```

gives correct error:

> LinearProgramming::lpsnf: No solution can be found that satisfies the constraints.

From my point of view this is a buggy behaviour, or did I miss something? Can someone confirm this for newer *Mathematica* versions?

Comment: Apparently a bug. Fixed in 8.0.4, though I didn't try 8.0.0 or 8.0.1.

Comment: What @Oleksandr R. said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a bug (as confirmed by Daniel Lichtblau). The good news is that it's been fixed at least as of version 8.0.4, and possibly earlier--I didn't try with versions 8.0.0 or 8.0.1.